# Virtuemart product filter error

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am using Joomla 1.7 and virtue-mart 2.0.6 for my website. In the administrator product filter section there is a date filter section. and this is not working. I have searched the the product model for this, but there is no condition they have written for handling this.
Is anybody faced this type problem? please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Describe what is happening in more detail.  What do you expect to happen?  What happens instead?

Comment: Th problem is we have product listing page in admin , there is a filter section , such as by catgeory, manufacturer .... also we have a datepicker to filter the products based on date. whenever we clicked on the date picker he value is not updating .. there is no javascript error here. i didnt add any custom codes..

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of little thing in the search filters that have changed a lot since VM1. I too have noticed the lack of support for many of the old fields.  Did you know that metadata is no longer searchable either?

Personally I have been hacking the administrator/components/com_virtuemart/models/product.php's sortSearchListQuery() function to do what I want it to do.

I would strongly recommend that you post the bug on the [VM dev portal](http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?board=127.0). The development community is very active and the more people that point out these bugs the better it will make VM for all!